# What framework/library to use for custom animated controls

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl, quartz-graphics

We are making an app whose primary purpose is to display data, but we want to do so in a rich way. Our design includes several custom controls.

For example, one control will be a wheel the user can spin to pick a time of day. You see an entire circle - a disk - that has time values going out like spokes from the center. It needs to spin around the center. So -- it's nothing like apple's picker. It needs to animate nicely.

What library/framework would you recommend to do this? Quartz? OpenGL? Is there a 3rd party framework that people use that makes this kind of thing simpler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Animation (i.e. CALayers) should be your first choice for animating objects that play nicely with UIKit. It has very good performance.